# Swap cooler on server hardware

Tags: cpu, cooling

I was asked to make a Primergy TX140 S1p FTS Server quieter than it currently is. You can hear it from behind the cupboard (its in a pharmacy).

The server uses a Intel Xeon E3-1220v3 with a FCLGA1150 socket.

Can I use any cooling system designed for FCLGA1150 (like for a i7-4770K), or is there something special I have to look out for in server hardware?

It has an airflow system installed, but the fan is ridiculously loud, and probably cheap (otherwise it wouldnt be as loud as it is). The CPU has a TDP of 80W, while 4770K has 84W, so every cooler for 4770K should be able to handle the Xeon.

Am I wrong with my assumptions, or can I go ahead and change the cooling system?

Comment: Before you start changing hardware, make sure that the rest is ok. E.g. how hot is it behind the cupboard? Is it getting a flow of fresh (cold) air or is there an obstruction?  Where is the hot air exhausted? (make sure it does not circulate back in). Does the fan speed (and noise) decrease after boot. (Servers usually spin it at max rev, then boot and the drivers then turn the fans down to what is needed. If they stay at the same speed in a cool room you have an other problem. ... ...

Comment: I will check some of these things later. Unfortunately its in live running, so I can only test things before and after the pharmacy hours. The cool air is blown into the server at the top of the case (it looks more or less like a regular desktop), so that is stupid design #1. The only exhaust I found are the regular ones, like in the top or the front / back of the case. It looks quite like a regular desktop, but with server hardware in it (unmarked mainboard, so I do not know who manufactured it, and similar)